# IOS Complex JSON Structure Parsing

Tags: ios, iphone, json, xcode

I Want to parse complex JSON structure JSON is given Below USING IOS.

What lib should i use, or any other lib`s custom available

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address":
     {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber":
     [
         {
           "type": "home",
           "number": "212 555-1234"
         },
         {
           "type": "fax",
           "number": "646 555-4567"
         }
     ]
 }
```

Comment: This is what I use in some of my objc projects. https://github.com/EasyMapping/EasyMapping

Comment: thanks i will try this .

Comment: if any1 have code for this this plz share ? .. code i used not working ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the JSON data into an NSData object, and use NSJSONSerialization's **JSONObjectWithData:options:error:** method.  The result will be an NSDictionary containing NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray objects.

So for example:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///myfile.txt"]]; // Probably get this from somewhere else, but you get the idea.

NSError *error = nil;
id topObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error: &error];

if ([topObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && !error) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure how I could give a useful example of that.  It's a single method that takes an NSData object containing the JSON data, pass 0 for options, and pass a reference to an NSError *error = nil; to get the error back.

Comment: Okay, minimal example, but the only really interesting bit is going to be getting the data into the NSData object to begin with, which is entirely dependent on what you're doing.  :-)